# .Net applications and user computers (Framework 3.5)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, frameworks

I have an application that I developed in Visual Studio .Net with the Framework 3.5; I have the following questions:

1. It's necessary that all the users have installed the Framework 3.5?
2. What is the difference between Framework X.xx and Framework X.xx Client profile? (I'm using the Framework Client Profile).

-- All users have installed the Office 2003 or superior.

-- The users can have installed the Windows XP or Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, however Windows 7 (and Server 2008) come with .NET 3.5 already installed. Check whether you need service pack or updates in order for your application to work correctly.
2. [Client framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is a subset of the full framework, later ones are optimised for client computers (ie not server processes) and as of .NET 4.5, the client profile is no longer an option - you have to use the full version instead.

Comment: When the user install the Office in the Windows XP, the framework not install automatically?

Comment: @MiBol almost certainly not - Office 2003 was released in 2003, .NET 3.5 was released in 2007.